# "TypeError: $.browser is undefined" using Primefaces Scrollable TreeTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm getting this strange error when I try to use a scrollable TreeTable (but it does not happen using a non-scrollable TreeTable) component.

[image]

The component simply does not collapse or expand on click if I add

`style="margin-top:0" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"`

to the p:treeTable component.

If I remove this, it works like a charm.

Tried with both primefaces 4 and 5 community.

Running on tomcat 7, using mojarra 2.2.0. (added by eclipse), Oracle Java 7.

Trying to run on both firefox 30.0, chrome 35 and IE 11.

Looks like some deprecated JQuery method, but why primefaces 4 and 5 would distribute their single jar with the wrong JQuery?

**Sounds like I am missing something here. What should I do to fix that?**

I've created a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse Kepler RC1, here goes the configuration info (pretty vanilla)

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>prime</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

faces.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
        <p:treeTable value="#{tree.root}" var="document" style="margin-top:0" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150">
            <f:facet name="header">
            Document Viewer
        </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Size">
                <h:outputText value="#{document.size}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Type">
                <h:outputText value="#{document.type}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

managed bean

```
package prime;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean(name = "tree")
@ViewScoped
public class TreeBean  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TreeNode root;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = createDocuments();
//        root.getChildren().get(0).setExpanded(true);
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public TreeNode createDocuments() {
        TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document("Files", "-", "Folder"), null);
        TreeNode documents = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document("Documents", "-", "Folder"), root);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            new DefaultTreeNode("document", new Document("doc"+i, "40 KB", "Document"), documents);
        }
       return root;
    }
}
```

entity bean

```
package prime;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Document implements Serializable, Comparable<Document> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private String size;

    private String type;

    public Document(String name, String size, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    //Eclipse Generated hashCode and equals
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((size == null) ? 0 : size.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Document other = (Document) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (size == null) {
            if (other.size != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!size.equals(other.size))
            return false;
        if (type == null) {
            if (other.type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Document document) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(document.getName());
    }
}
```

facets

[image]

Comment: use jQuery Migrate plugin..

Comment: adding jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js to WebContent\resources\js and [h:outputScript name="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" library="js" target="head"] did the trick, thanks! Is there any reason why Primefaces is not distributing this js library by default? (feel free to add your answer, so I can accept it and give you the points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.browser is deprecated function in jquery latest. To use the deprecated function, use jquery migrate plugin

> The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older
>   code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later.